# awk to compare more than two files

Tags: unix, awk

Would like to compare  first field ($1) of f11.txt and f22.txt with first field ($1) of f33.txt then print `non-matching line items from f33.txt`

f11.txt

```
a,b
c,d
```

f22.txt

```
a,b
x,x
```

f33.txt

```
a,b
z,z
```

Have tried below command and in-complete

```
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$1] = $0; next} !($1 in a) {print $0}'  f11.txt f22.txt f33.txt
```

Expected Output from f33.txt:

```
z,z
```

Would like to compare  first field ($1) of f11.txt,f22.txt,f33.txt with first field ($1) of f44.txt then print `non-matching line items from f44.txt`

where f44.txt

```
m,n
x,y
b,a
```

Have tried below command and in-complete

```
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$1] = $0; next} !($1 in a) {print $0}'  f11.txt f22.txt f33.txt f44.txt
```

Expected Output from f44.txt:

```
m,n
b,a
```

Looking for your suggestions !!

Comment: nash_ag , the above link for comparing two files Only , so my question is not duplicate one ...

Comment: Can you start (in the first case) with `cat f11 f22 > f11_22` and then use the technique for comparing two files?

Comment: comparing multiple files and columns using awk link is not similar with above question ...

Comment: Jas , I was doing like that only as Step1 is cat f11 f22> f11_22 then Step2 as f11_f22 vs f33 , curiosity to understand to avoid two steps ...

Comment: To avoid two steps you need your awk to build the index from the first n-1 files, and then print non-matching lines only from the nth (last) file. (Your current awk is building the index only from the first file.)

Comment: Jas thanks for the inputs, could you please provide sample command as am not able to do in one step ...

Comment: Research the built-in awk variables `FILENAME`, `ARGV`, and `ARGC` (plus `ARGIND` if using gawk). With those you can know if you are processing the last file.

Comment: Or just turn around and put `f33` as the first file, and change the logic accordingly.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405099/how-to-compare-one-file-with-bunch-of-files-in-linux/27407159#27407159 for an answer along the lines of @tripleee's excellent alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's 2 possibilities:

1. read `f33.txt` first, store the lines, and for each subsequent files remove stored lines

   ```
   awk -F, '
       NR==FNR {f33[$1]=$0; next} 
       $1 in f33 {delete f33[$1]} 
       END {for (key in f33) print f33[key]}
   ' f33.txt f11.txt f22.txt
   ```
2. examine the current file with the last filename in the arguments

   ```
   awk -F, '
       FILENAME != ARGV[ARGC-1] {keys[$1]; next} 
       !($1 in keys)
   ' f11.txt f22.txt f33.txt
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot Glenn Jackman for your good support ,Its working fine , I have accepted the answer and upvoted !!!